# Menu Bar Apps Using QT

Tags: c++, macos, qt

Was wondering if using QT is it possible to make menu bar / task bar apps, like The menubar apps described here http://blog.shpakovski.com/2011/07/cocoa-popup-window-in-status-bar.html.

I'm aware of the various system tray icons that can trigger dialogs and open windows, but was curious to see if a full app / dialog could be integrated. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question, I've never thought about doing this before. After some quick googling, I located the following answer:

[System Tray Example QT 4.8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-desktop-systray-example.html)
[System Tray Example QT 5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-systray-example.html)

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but it appears that you can integrate an entire window application to this system tray icon. It's at least a start to writing a tray icon program.

**EDIT**: updated links to new docs.

Comment: Looks like the link you originally linked to has gone dead, but I believe this talks on something similar - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/desktop-systray.html